# unable to set lock screen in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: unity, lock-screen, dconf

I am using dconf-editor to change my lock screen , but it always falls back to default one. I'd tried every method that's possible using dconf-editor, but unable to do so . what's the possible way to change it ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the permissions on the image you're using to make sure other users & groups have read access to the image? Usually it will revert to the default lock screen when it doesn't have sufficient privileges to read the file (as it will be owned by your user).

Comment: Permission are same as the default one . Even after giving it a full permission it revert backs to original one .